# how to invoke and pass arguments to an int array

Tags: java

//Write a method public static int calculateSum(int[] array) that takes as input an int[] and returns the sum of the values of the array

```
public class additionArray{ 
  public static void main(String[]args){ 
    calculateSum(); // this wont work; i dont get how to pass parameters to the array?
  }
 public static int calculateSum(int[] array)
{
 int sum = 0;
 for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++)
 {
  sum = sum + array[i];
 }

 return sum;
 }}
```

Comment: It's *your* homework. Show what *you* think the answer is, say what part isn't doing what you expect, and why you're expecting something else. People are happy to help. They are not happy to do your work for you.

Comment: the question is, how am i to pass arguments to the method calculateSum ...?

Comment: first off, its not homework, i'm trying to get the hang of arrays, so please refrain from commenting if you cant help @ T.J. Crowder

Comment: Please edit your question above to make it clear what you want to ask!

Comment: Please click the 'help' link at the top of the page and go to the section where it explains how this site is supposed to be used and what behaviour is expected from you when asking questions, if you don't want everybody to downvote your question.

Comment: @user2997263: Oh, that kind of attitude is very constructive. I'm well-known for my unhelpfulness here. *"Write a method public static int calculateSum(int[] array) that takes as input an int[] and returns the sum of the values of the array"* reads as a homework assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just create one and pass.

```
   public static void main(String[]args){
         int[] intArray=new int[]{1,2};   //took sample elements
         int sum = calculateSum(intArray); // create an array and pass here.
      }
```

I took the integers 1,2 for test

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to create the `int[]` to give to `calculateSum` based on the `String[]` that `main` receives, the answer is:

1. Create an `int[]` that has the same size as the `String[]`.
2. Loop through `String[]` array, parsing each `String` (e.g., [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)) into an `int` and then filling in the equivalent slot in your `int[]` array.
3. Pass your `int[]` into `calculateSum`.

You should probably also show the result of `calculateSum`, for instance perhaps with `System.out.println`.